# AngularJS JSONP SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsonp

I am trying to use the [WordsAPI](https://www.wordsapi.com/) and everytime I try to access it using jsnop and Angular I get this error:

[image]

The code I am using is the following:

```
  $scope.searchWord = function() {
var url = 'https://www.wordsapi.com/words/'+$scope.word+'/definitions?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&accessToken=ACCESS_TOKEN';
$http.jsonp(url).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.meanings = data;
  console.log($scope.meanings)
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

}

So it should be getting something like:
https://www.wordsapi.com/words/word/definitions?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&accessToken=ACCESS_TOKEN

I tested this link on JSON validators and everything is fine with the JSON it gets from the server.
I am using Chrome on a Mac.

Does Anyone have any idea ?

Comment: JSON is not the same thing as JSONP. the API is returning the wrong datatype for your request.

Comment: If an API requires an access token, it's unlikely that the api was meant to be used directly within the browser. Such apis rarely offer jsonp as an option because servers have no issues requesting cross-domain.

Comment: I'm actually still a little curious why he's getting a SyntaxError. Without the P (Padding) on the JSON you can't use it anyway - but I'd think any valid JSON would eval as JavaScript without issues. I also don't think it's true that all APIs need to be used by a server.

Comment: *"I also don't think it's true that all APIs need to be used by a server."* that's not at all what i said.

Comment: SaraVieira, I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution ?