# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in angular using JsonP

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a cross domain service that i that returns a json object. I am using JSON $http.jsonp(). But am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: **Unexpected token : in angular using JsonP**. How do i convert a json to jsonp or is there any better means to slove these issue

```
      $resource( APIS.GET,
            {
               callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
            },

            {
               getBeacon: {
                   method: "JSONP",
                   isArray: false,
               },

            },{
                stripTrailingSlashes :false
            }
        );
```

Comment: please post the code that throws the exception please.

Comment: Any difference if you use a construction like $http.get(url).then(function(data){ return angular.fromJson(data); }) ?

Comment: duplicate for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848003/angularjs-jsonp-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: @STEVER That post has no answer.

Comment: @chris  results in a CORS issue

Comment: @STEVER cant find an answer there either

Comment: CORS issue, well what backend are you calling, .net / java other?

Comment: @chris  $http.jsonp( url) the service is a  restful service. and it works well i just want to retrieve data how does POSTMAN do it